# webView height should change when transitioning to landscape

Tags: swift, webview, viewwilltransitiontosize

In need of some help here, please.

I have this webView that loads a html text.
The webview is inside a scrollView below other elements(an image, a stack view).
I set its height like this

```
func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: UIWebView) {
    heightWebView.constant = webView.scrollView.contentSize.height
}
```

Everything is fine when I enter the view controller and scroll through it, but when I change from Portrait to Landscape, I do not have enough space in the scroll view to scroll the whole webView and the inscroll of the Webview activates.

Any ideea what I should do?
I already tried in

```
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
```

to reset the height of the webView like in *webViewDidFinishLoad*, but it didn't work.